# Generating a sequence from a number using RNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Can someone please provide me with a neat example about generating a sequence from a number using RNN? (Possibly without using `NetGraph[]`.)

Edit:
I'm trying to build an LSTM autoencoder, I have to take an embedding and generate a sequence, I'm trying to use a NetChain[] with different LongShortTermMemoryLayer[] but cannot figure out how to input a single number.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please define RNN.

Comment: Recurrent networks generally transform sequences to new sequences in much the same way as `FoldList`. They do not produce sequences from a single number.